# Changing appcompat alertdialog accent color made all dialogs smaller

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles

So I wanted to change my alertdialogs accent color, I added this to my styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and this into my base style:

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.AlertDialogTheme</item>
```

Color is changed, thats cool, but now all my dialogs are smaller. How can I retain the size while changing the color?

[Here is before/after album.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoUoO.jpg)

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` is not the right style to extend I think. Otherwise, try adding `<item name="windowMinWidthMajor">@dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>` and `<item name="windowMinWidthMinor">@dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>` to `AppTheme.AlertDialogTheme`. `dialog_min_width_major` will be 65%(normal), 55%(large) and 45%(x-large). `dialog_min_width_minor` will be 95%(normal), 80%(large) and 72%(x-large).

Answer (score 7):

From looking at the google iosched code, the alertdialog theme needs to inherit from Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert not just Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog .

Two caveats. One, the result is wider than it was before, but at least it's not as narrow as wrap content.
Two, this caused weird behavior on pre-L devices.
Ultimately, I ended up creating all alerts with

```
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,
            R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert_Custom
```

This worked fine for Alert Dialogs and Dialogs but for some reason it did not theme Progress Dialogs.
I had to remove android:alertDialogTheme from my base theme and put it in a v21/styles.xml only in order to theme Progress Dialogs without bad behavior (double backgrounds) on Pre-L devices.

Answer (score 4):

There are two styles for dialogs: [`alertDialogTheme`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#alertDialogTheme) for alert dialogs, and [`dialogTheme`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#dialogTheme) for other dialogs (such as `DatePickerDialog`, for example, although that one can also be customized more specifically). They key point is that each of these needs a **different** base style, since they have different layout parameters.

Therefore, to theme dialogs properly, make your `values-v21\styles.xml` file more or less like this:

```
<!-- Theme -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppThemeDialog</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppThemeAlertDialog</item>
</style>

<!-- Styles for dialogs in Lollipop, use accent color from applicable theme. -->
<style name="AppThemeDialog" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppThemeAlertDialog" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

This is for the *Light with Dark Action Bar* variant, although the Light and Dark versions are approximately the same, just changing parent styles everywhere.

As an advantage, this setup will read the `accentColor` set in the application theme, so do you not need to repeat them here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog** instead of proper theme for AlertDialogs: **Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert**. There is no theme for AlertDialogs in AppCompat as far as I know, so use it only in values-v21 folder.